# Quickest way to teach myself college algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to teach myself college algebra and precalculus. What's the quickest / most efficient way to do this?

I took Algebra I & II a long time ago, but I don't remember most of it. Recently I've reviewed Algebra I and a lot of Algebra II, and now I'm up to the more advanced parts of Algebra II.

I need a resource that's self-paced (I don't want to be tied down to a slow teaching schedule) and as quick and efficient as I can get, but it needs to be comprehensive. I also need some way of testing myself to make sure I understand and remember the concepts.

So far I've tried a some of the Cliffs Quick Review series and Khan Academy. They're both quick and self-paced, but I'm concerned they're not comprehensive enough. Also, Cliffs doesn't have much self-testing, and Khan Academy lacks quizzes on many topics.

Answer (score 1):

Use these video lectures (free) from Harvard. They also include notes taken by a great TA so it is very accessible:

http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra

They follow Artin's "Algebra" which is, in my opinion, quite intuitive for the beginning part on groups.

Then, if you are wanting a text for rings and fields, I would switch to "Dummit & Foote" which, in my opinion, gives a better presentation.

No matter what, do problems. Practice, practice, practice. You can always get outstanding help here.

EDIT: If this is more advanced than you intended, here is a great book by a great mathematician, I. Gelfand:

[http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Israel-M-Gelfand/dp/0817636773](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817636773)

Comment: I *think* the OP is talking about this kind of algebra: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/Alg.aspx , rather than group theory.

Comment: @DepeHb Yes, I think you are right. That's why I stuck in the "Gelfand" suggestion.

Comment: I was asking about the less advanced type. The link from DepeHb looks very interesting, as does the book from I.M. Gelfand.  Does anyone know about the [Art of Problem Solving curriculum](http://http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/index.php?mode=books)?

Answer (score 0):

youtube is a great source if you want to search up lectures and there are many math textbooks available online for free in pdf format